# How to get multiple desktop layouts per user? (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, desktop

By desktop layouts I mean simply the files on the desktop for example I would like to have one desktop with files for programming the other for keeping track of stuff... you get the idea. Is there a way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**
to clarify: by desktop I mean the stuff you see on the most of your screen you  see by default (contents of the desktop file) my question is how can I swap another file with the desktop file so I can have "multiple desktops".

Comment: @McDonald's look on the update

Comment: If you're not talking about Virtual Desktop feature built into Windows 10 --> Press WinKey+Ctrl+D, and you get a virtual desktop you can put stuff there and then to toggle after that, you WinKey+Ctrl+Left Arrow (or Right Arrow too perhaps). Otherwise, create a desktop folder for programming and another for other stuff and simply open those two different folder for the correlated content to help you organize and differentiate rather than a slew of files right on the desktop which can turn ugly real quick. Just change your habits a bit and test, etc. and you'll be all good. Good Luck!

Comment: Check out --> http://www.thewindowsclub.com/keyboard-shortcuts-taskbar-virtual-desktops for some detail on Virtual Desktop. In case you find this helpful, you can look this over too perhaps if you need help or some ideas about such sort of a process https://superuser.com/questions/1224564/how-to-load-startup-programs-on-different-task-views/1228351#1228351

Comment: The closest (possibly the exact) thing to what you're asking is "Virtual desktops". See the comments above.