# How to open Windows+Tab in command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, batch, desktop

From a batch file, is it possible to open the Desktop view like when you press the Windows Key and the Tab Key? Preferably in one command.

Comment: I’m relatively sure this is part of the explorer.exe shell  and not a separate process on its own. You would need something like AutoHotkey to bring it up. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Open it from a rain meter script. I figured there was an explorer shell code.

Comment: @MarkDeven - I wrote an answer here for something similar but not exactly the same if I understand you correctly, this may be what you are looking for. https://superuser.com/questions/1224564/how-to-load-startup-programs-on-different-task-views/1228351#1228351. . . Let me know if something like that would suffice for opening a specific Virtual Desktop.

Comment: Thanks! I made an exe that does the same thing. I’ll post it once I’m @ work

Comment: Already done! thx!

Answer (score 0):

I made this executable that does just what I needed:
https://github.com/ITCMD/Win-Tab